# Undefined global variable in python when using classes

Tags: python

```
from bookrecmodified import *
import tkinter as tk



#button = tk.Button(canvas, text="Friends",bg="white",fg="black")
#button.pack()


#button = tk.Button(canvas, text="Recommend",bg = 'white',fg='black')
#button.pack()

#button = tk.Button(canvas, text="Report", bg = "white", fg="black")
#button.pack()



class BuckysButtons:

    def __init__(self, master):
        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack()

        self.printButton = Button(frame, text="Print Message", command=self.printMessage)
        self.printButton.pack(side=LEFT)


        self.quitButton = Button(frame, text="Quit", command=frame.quit)
        self.quitButton.pack(side=LEFT)

        def printMessage(self):
            print("WOw")





    def printMessage(self):
        print("Wow this actually works")










root = tk.Tk()
b = BuckysButtons(root)
root.mainloop
```

I have a class that is for a GUI i am trying to make a class for it. I followed a youtube video tutorial and im wondering why I am getting a global variable not defined error

For some reason I am getting a undefined variable scope for the frame, when it is clearly defined in the **init_** function. Why is it stating its undefined? I do not understand

```
 frame = Frame(master)
NameError: global name 'Frame' is not defined
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you really have one class called "Buttom" and one called "BUttom"?

Comment: apologize, quickly copied and pasted the code. Will modify it to fix it. Still gets the global variable incorrect

Comment: Precisely what error are receiving? Please include this in your post with an [edit], including the exceptions, stacktrace, etc.

Comment: edited to add the error. Thanks @Brian

Comment: Where is `Frame` defined? You do not explicitly import it, and it is impossible to tell if you expect it to come from `bookrecmodified` if you use a glob import.

Comment: it is defined in the __init__ function

Comment: `import *` is generally bad practice, be careful.

Answer (score 0):

The way you wrote your import, you want `tk.Frame` and `tk.Button`. You could do

```
from tkinter import *
```

or

```
from tkinter import Frame, Button
```

but personally I prefer the `tk.Frame` (and etc...) way of doing things so that the reader isn't left guessing what type of frame it is.